# Embeddings of 3 point metric spaces into ultra-metric spaces with distortion 2

Tags: metric-spaces

I need to show that every 3 point metric space has an embedding into an ultra-metric space with distortion 2.

And then to show such an example.

How would I go about it?

Thank you.

**Edit:**
Distortion is defined as following:
An embedding $f:(X,d_X)\rightarrow(Y,d_Y)$ has distortion $\alpha$ if there is a constant $c>0$ such that $\forall u,v\in X:d_X(u,v)\leq c \cdot d_Y(f(x),f(y))\leq \alpha \cdot d_X(u,v)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the three-point metric space be $\langle X,d_X\rangle$, where $X=\{x_0,x_1,x_2\}$. We can label the three points in such a way that $d_X(x_0,x_1)\le d_X(x_1,x_2)\le d_X(x_0,x_2)$, and the triangle inequality ensures that $d_X(x_0,x_2)\le d_X(x_0,x_1)+d_X(x_1,x_2)\le 2d_X(x_1,x_2)$.

Let $\langle Y,d_Y\rangle$ be the ultrametric space, and let $Y=\{y_0,y_1,y_2\}$, where $y_k=f(x_k)$ for $k=0,1,2$. Let $d_Y(y_0,y_1)=d_X(x_0,x_1)$ and $d_Y(y_1,y_2)=d_X(x_1,x_2)$.

- Bearing in mind that $d_Y$ is an ultrametric, what must $d_Y(y_0,y_2)$ be?
- Check that the embedding $f:X\to Y:x_k\mapsto y_k$ has distortion $2$.

Comment: Thank you, much clearer now!

Comment: @user83155: You’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott -I still can't figure out how to show that 
$$d_X \left( x_0 , x_2 \right) \leqslant 2 \cdot d_Y \left( y_0 , y_2 \right)$$ (Assuming that our constant $c$ equals 2).

Comment: @Amihai: $d_Y(y_0,y_2)$ has to be the same as $d_Y(y_1,y_2)$, so $$d_X(x_0,x_2)\le2d_X(x_1,x_2)=2d_Y(y_0,y_2)\;.$$

Comment: And that's because it's an ultra-metric space? - many thanks!

Comment: @Amihai: Yes, that’s why the two longer distances have to be equal. It’s not hard to prove that in an ultrametric space every triangle is isosceles, with two longer sides and a shorter one, or equilateral.

Comment: Isn't it for an ultra metric space $X$:
$$\forall x, y, z \in X:\text{ }d(x,y)\leqslant \max{d(x,z),d(z,y)}$$ and not equality??

Comment: @Amihai: Yes, it is. And that’s enough to give the result about triangles. Suppose that the sides are $a\le b\le c$. Then we have $b\le c\le\max\{a,b\}=b$, so $b=c$.

Comment: Yes, now I see (the obvious)... Thanks again!

Comment: @Amihai: You’re welcome!